# CSS display property not working as expected

Tags: html, css

When trying to create a `cursor: pointer` effect for id's in my html the format alignment changes and I can't figure out why. For instance, the `id="mile-buff"` jumps up to the next line when applying.

```
#tracks, #mile-buff{
     display: inline-flex;
     cursor: pointer;
 }
```

The reason I included `display: inline-flex` is because it's the only way I found to limit the pointer to the text/div and not include white space. But again, it keeps messing with the alignment. Any help would be appreciated, thanks. Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prime90/bzc1jt3v/21/)

```css
#tracks, #mile-buff{
     display: inline-flex;
     cursor: pointer;
 }
 
 
 .legend-body {
     width: 240px;
     box-shadow: 5px 10px 18px #888888;
     background:#f5f5f5;
     font-size: 14px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     padding: 20px;
}
 .layer-text {
     display: block;
     text-indent: 40px;
}
/* fill icons for legend */
 .layer-fill {
     width: 25px;
     height: 15px;
     margin: 5px;
     border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
     position: absolute;
     display: flex;
     
}
 .one-mile {
     background: #76d7c4;
     opacity: .5;
}
 .half-mile {
     background: #f7dc6f;
     opacity: .5;
}
 .onehun-yrds {
     background: #ec7063;
     opacity: .5;
}
/* line icons for legend */
 .layer-line{
     border: 0;
     width: 25px;
     height: 1px;
     margin-top: 11px;
     margin-left: 5px;
     position: absolute;
     display: flex;
}
 .tracks {
     background-color: #000;
}
 .hclanes {
     background-color: #3498db;
     height: 2px;
}
 .lclanes {
     background-color: #3498db;
}
 .paved {
     background-color: #138d75;
     height: 2px;
}
 .natural {
    /*10px color then 2px transparent -> repeat this for dash lines!*/
     background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right,#138d75 0,#138d75 11px,transparent 11px,transparent 14px) 
}
```

```html
<div class="legend-body" id= "legend">
  <b>Railroad Layers</b>
  <div class='train-layer-options'>
      <div class="layer-line tracks" id="tracks"></div>
      <a class="layer-text" id="tracks">Tracks<br></a>
      <div class="layer-fill one-mile" id="mile-buff"></div>
      <a class="layer-text" id="mile-buff">Sound Buffer (1 mile)<br></a>
      <div class="layer-fill half-mile"></div>
      <span class="layer-text">Sound Buffer (1/2 mile)<br></span>
      <div class="layer-fill onehun-yrds"></div>
      <span class="layer-text">Sound Buffer (100 yards)<br></span>
  </div>
  <b>Bike Lane Layers</b>
  <div class='bike-layer-options'>
      <div class="layer-line hclanes"></div>
      <span class="layer-text">High Comfort Lanes<br></span>
      <div class="layer-line lclanes"></div>
      <span class="layer-text">Low Comfort Lanes<br></span>
  </div>
  <b>Multiuse Trail Layers</b>
  <div class='bike-layer-options'>
      <div class="layer-line paved"></div>
      <span class="layer-text">Paved Trails<br></span>
      <div class="layer-line natural"></div>
      <span class="layer-text">Natural Trails<br></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have more than one element with the same ID. Element IDs should be unique within the entire document.
So, without muliple IDs `#tracks` and `#mile-buff`, here is the HTML:

```
<div class="legend-body" id= "legend">
  <b>Railroad Layers</b>
  <div class='train-layer-options'>
    <div class="layer-line tracks" id="tracks"></div>
    <a class="layer-text">Tracks<br></a>
    <div class="layer-fill one-mile" id="mile-buff"></div>
    <a class="layer-text">Sound Buffer (1 mile)<br></a>
    <div class="layer-fill half-mile"></div>
    <span class="layer-text">Sound Buffer (1/2 mile)<br></span>
    <div class="layer-fill onehun-yrds"></div>
    <span class="layer-text">Sound Buffer (100 yards)<br></span>
  </div>
  <b>Bike Lane Layers</b>
  <div class='bike-layer-options'>
    <div class="layer-line hclanes"></div>
    <span class="layer-text">High Comfort Lanes<br></span>
    <div class="layer-line lclanes"></div>
    <span class="layer-text">Low Comfort Lanes<br></span>
  </div>
  <b>Multiuse Trail Layers</b>
  <div class='bike-layer-options'>
    <div class="layer-line paved"></div>
    <span class="layer-text">Paved Trails<br></span>
    <div class="layer-line natural"></div>
    <span class="layer-text">Natural Trails<br></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

It will already solve the alignment issue, because it will remove some unnecessary CSS.

Then, on `.layer-text` class, you can replace identation for left margin and add `cursor: pointer`.

```
.layer-text {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Finally, you just have to add `cursor: pointer` on any ID you want.
Or on `.layer-fill` class if you prefer.

Comment: Sweet thanks! Is it possible to have the cursor only engage over the text and not the white space to the right of the text?

Comment: No problem. Yes. I would recommend to wrap the text within a span like this: ``<a class="layer-text"><span>Tracks</span><br></a>``, then add the cursor to the span: ``.layer-text span { cursor: pointer }``. Don't forget to remove the ``cursor: pointer`` from ``.layer-text`` class.